# Jquery auto hide/close mobile div nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When viewed on mobile, I currently have a side main menu that wont "auto close" when clicked outside of its div. I'm a total novice when it comes to JQuery, found the code that manipulates the menu. But I have no idea what to change in order for the menu to auto close when clicking outside of its div.  Menu can be found here and seen in mobile view. https://www.poupos.fr/dev/ Thank you.

Js

```
// sidebar
$('.menu-button').on("click", function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-experience')) {
   $("body").removeClass('mobile-experience');
  } else {
   $("body").addClass('mobile-experience');
  }
  navWorksWidth($(window).scrollTop());
});

// hidden container
$('.open-hidden-container').on("click", function() {
 if ($('.hidden-container, .hidden-container-left').hasClass('open')) {
   $(".hidden-container, .hidden-container-left").removeClass('open');
   $(".hidden-container, .hidden-container-left").addClass('close');
 } else {
   $(".hidden-container, .hidden-container-left").removeClass('close');
   $(".hidden-container, .hidden-container-left").addClass('open');
 }
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="" id="header">     
  <div class="logo">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<!-- menu bar start -->
<div class="" id="menu">
  <!-- navigation start -->
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
     <li>
       <span class="navscroll tooltip link-underline" data-idpage="page-home">Home<sup class="box-tooltip">Home</sup></span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <span class="navscroll tooltip link-underline" data-idpage="page-anna">About Anna<sup class="box-tooltip">About Anna</sup></span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <span class="navscroll tooltip link-underline" data-idpage="page-lessons">Lessons<sup class="box-tooltip">Lessons</sup></span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <span class="navscroll tooltip link-underline" data-idpage="page-media">Media<sup class="box-tooltip">Media</sup></span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <span class="navscroll tooltip link-underline" data-idpage="page-contact">Contact<sup class="box-tooltip">Contact</sup></span>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- navigation end -->  
</div>
<!-- menu bar end -->

<!-- mobile navigation button start -->
<div class="bt-mobile">
  <div class="menu menu-button open">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- mobile navigation button end -->
```

Comment: Include the html also please.

Comment: Add a click event to the document. Check if the target is anything else but the menu / menu items and remove / add classes from there on out. Something like `document.addEventListener('click',function(e){ if(e.target && e.target.id != 'your_menu_id_here'){ $('.body').removeClass('mobile-experience'); } });`

Answer (score 0):

you can add new function click with parent (of menu and content) or only content

```
   $('.page-home').on("click", function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-experience')) {
        $("body").removeClass('mobile-experience');
    } else {
        $("body").addClass('mobile-experience');
    }
    navWorksWidth($(window).scrollTop());
});
//
```

Note: you should use toggleClass change addClass and removeClass

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a complete n00b with this code. I don't understand "you should use toggleClass change addClass and removeClass". And when testing the code, nothing works, however when I change ".page-home" to just "body". It kinda works. Menu button doesn't work to open menu, but when I click randomly somewhere on the page, the menu opens up, click again, menu closes. I will keep fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around I did this, and it works!

```
        // sidebar
    $('.menu-button').on("click", function() {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-experience')) {
            $("body").removeClass('mobile-experience');
        } else {
            $("body").addClass('mobile-experience');
        }
        navWorksWidth($(window).scrollTop());
    });

    $("html").click(function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).closest('.menu-button').length == 0)
        $("body").removeClass('mobile-experience');
    });
    //
```